# how we integrate apptentive with zoho support?

Tags: zoho

Currently, users communicate through their mobile devices which creates a thread on Apptentive, which we can then respond to back to the user’s mobile application. We need to integrate these conversations in zoho support as a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Sample URL:
;https://support.zoho.com/api/xml/requests/addrecords?authtoken=AUTHTOKEN&portal=demosupport&department=demodepartment&xml=XMLDATA`
XMLDATA should be the following format:
https://www.zoho.com/support/help/api/add-records.html